# Php warnings after moving site (preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string , Cannot modify header information )

Tags: php-errors

Need some advice on what is going on here - move my site to a new server and now I'm getting these two errors/warnings. EE should have write access. So not sure what is causing it. EE running version v2.5.3. ( PHP Version 5.2.17 , apache 2.0 or 2.2 )

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/File_field.php

Line Number: 437
```

And this

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/governme/public_html/sys/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 408
```

Code in line 437

```
> public function parse_field($data)    {       // If the file field is in the
> "{filedir_n}image.jpg" format         if (preg_match('/^{filedir_(\d+)}/',
> $data, $matches))         {           // Set upload directory ID and file name
>           $dir_id = $matches[1];          $file_name = str_replace($matches[0], '',
> $data);
>                       $file = $this->get_file($file_name, $dir_id);       }       // If file field is just a file ID      else if (! empty($data) &&
> is_numeric($data))        {           $file = $this->get_file($data);         }
> .............
```

code in line 408.

```
if (substr(php_sapi_name(), 0, 3) == 'cgi')
        {
            header("Status: {$code} {$text}", TRUE);
        }
```

Any ideas on what is causing this ?

Did the varDump .. this is the output.

```
string(77) "{filedir_4}From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_.png"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "192"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(66) "From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_.png"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(136) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_.png"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(66) "From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_.png"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(5) "60559"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360412744"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360412744"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(7) "441 310"
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(77) "{filedir_4}From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_.png"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(62) "From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_"
  ["url"]=>
  string(129) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_.png"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "310"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "441"
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(77) "{filedir_4}From_Customer_Satisfaction_Measurement_to_Customer-Centricity_.png"
string(115) "{filedir_4}Harnessing_the_Power_of_Publicâ€“Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments.png"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "193"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(104) "Harnessing_the_Power_of_Publicâ€“Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments.png"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(174) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Harnessing_the_Power_of_Publicâ€“Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments.png"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(110) "Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public%E2%80%93Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments.png"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(5) "47688"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413196"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413196"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(7) "438 312"
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(115) "{filedir_4}Harnessing_the_Power_of_Publicâ€“Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments.png"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(106) "Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public%E2%80%93Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments"
  ["url"]=>
  string(173) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public%E2%80%93Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments.png"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "312"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "438"
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(115) "{filedir_4}Harnessing_the_Power_of_Publicâ€“Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare-_Imperatives_for_GCC_Governments.png"
string(80) "{filedir_4}Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare.pdf"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "225"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(69) "Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare.pdf"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(139) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare.pdf"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(69) "Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare.pdf"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(7) "5467402"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360519816"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360519816"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(1) " "
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(80) "{filedir_4}Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare.pdf"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "pdf"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(65) "Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare"
  ["url"]=>
  string(132) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare.pdf"
  ["width"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["height"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(80) "{filedir_4}Harnessing_the_Power_of_Public-Private_Partnerships_in_Healthcare.pdf"
string(79) "{filedir_4}Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy.png"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "194"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(68) "Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy.png"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(138) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy.png"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(68) "Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy.png"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(5) "53832"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413462"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413462"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(7) "440 313"
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(79) "{filedir_4}Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy.png"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(64) "Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy"
  ["url"]=>
  string(131) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy.png"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "313"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "440"
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(79) "{filedir_4}Taking_a_more_sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_labour_Marjet_Policy.png"
string(69) "{filedir_4}Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG.pdf"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "211"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(58) "Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG.pdf"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(128) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG.pdf"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(58) "Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG.pdf"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(7) "1035735"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360488189"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360488189"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(1) " "
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(69) "{filedir_4}Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG.pdf"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "pdf"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(54) "Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG"
  ["url"]=>
  string(121) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG.pdf"
  ["width"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["height"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(69) "{filedir_4}Taking_a_More_Sophisticated_Approach_to_GCC_Labour_ENG.pdf"
string(36) "{filedir_4}Government_Efficiency.png"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "195"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(25) "Government_Efficiency.png"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(95) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Government_Efficiency.png"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(25) "Government_Efficiency.png"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(5) "50657"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413644"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413644"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(7) "438 310"
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(36) "{filedir_4}Government_Efficiency.png"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(21) "Government_Efficiency"
  ["url"]=>
  string(88) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Government_Efficiency.png"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "310"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "438"
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(36) "{filedir_4}Government_Efficiency.png"
string(27) "{filedir_4}Deloitte_ENG.pdf"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "206"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(16) "Deloitte_ENG.pdf"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(86) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Deloitte_ENG.pdf"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(16) "Deloitte_ENG.pdf"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(7) "1140040"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360485441"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360485441"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(1) " "
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(27) "{filedir_4}Deloitte_ENG.pdf"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "pdf"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(12) "Deloitte_ENG"
  ["url"]=>
  string(79) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Deloitte_ENG.pdf"
  ["width"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["height"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(27) "{filedir_4}Deloitte_ENG.pdf"
string(41) "{filedir_4}Citizen_Centric_Government.png"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "196"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(30) "Citizen_Centric_Government.png"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(100) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Citizen_Centric_Government.png"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(30) "Citizen_Centric_Government.png"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(5) "62054"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413858"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360413858"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(7) "438 312"
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(41) "{filedir_4}Citizen_Centric_Government.png"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(26) "Citizen_Centric_Government"
  ["url"]=>
  string(93) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Citizen_Centric_Government.png"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "312"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "438"
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(41) "{filedir_4}Citizen_Centric_Government.png"
string(41) "{filedir_4}AT_Kearny_Report_-_english.pdf"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "229"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(30) "AT_Kearny_Report_-_english.pdf"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(100) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/AT_Kearny_Report_-_english.pdf"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(30) "AT_Kearny_Report_-_english.pdf"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(7) "5125939"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360571001"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360571001"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(1) " "
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(41) "{filedir_4}AT_Kearny_Report_-_english.pdf"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "pdf"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(26) "AT_Kearny_Report_-_english"
  ["url"]=>
  string(93) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/AT_Kearny_Report_-_english.pdf"
  ["width"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["height"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(41) "{filedir_4}AT_Kearny_Report_-_english.pdf"
string(60) "{filedir_4}Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities.png"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "197"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(49) "Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities.png"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(119) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities.png"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(49) "Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities.png"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(5) "53832"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360414308"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360414308"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(7) "440 310"
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(60) "{filedir_4}Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities.png"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(45) "Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities"
  ["url"]=>
  string(112) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities.png"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "310"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "440"
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(60) "{filedir_4}Building_Citizen_Trust_in_Government_Entities.png"
string(41) "{filedir_4}Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG.pdf"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "205"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(30) "Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG.pdf"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(100) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG.pdf"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(30) "Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG.pdf"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(7) "1053860"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360484412"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360484412"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(1) " "
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(41) "{filedir_4}Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG.pdf"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "pdf"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(26) "Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG"
  ["url"]=>
  string(93) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG.pdf"
  ["width"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["height"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(41) "{filedir_4}Building_Citizen_Trust_ENG.pdf"
string(81) "{filedir_4}Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government.png"
array(29) {
  ["file_id"]=>
  string(3) "198"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(70) "Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government.png"
  ["upload_location_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["rel_path"]=>
  string(140) "/data/sites/web/governmentsummituaecom/www/assets/images/publications/Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government.png"
  ["mime_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/png"
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(70) "Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government.png"
  ["file_size"]=>
  string(5) "54180"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["credit"]=>
  NULL
  ["location"]=>
  NULL
  ["uploaded_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["upload_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360414548"
  ["modified_by_member_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["modified_date"]=>
  string(10) "1360414548"
  ["file_hw_original"]=>
  string(7) "439 308"
  ["raw_output"]=>
  string(81) "{filedir_4}Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government.png"
  ["path"]=>
  string(63) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(66) "Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government"
  ["url"]=>
  string(133) "http://www3.governmentsummituae.com/assets/images/publications/Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government.png"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "308"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "439"
  ["image_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_pre_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_post_format"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["file_properties"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(81) "{filedir_4}Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-driven_Decision_Making_in_Government.png"
string(85) "{filedir_4}Achieving_Excellence_via_Data-Driven_Decision_Making_in_Government_ENG.pdf"
```

............. had to crop because of post length

Comment: What version of PHP do you have on the old server?

Comment: Try `var_dump($data);` before line 437, and see what the data is. Maybe we can then figure out why it's an array instead of a string.

Comment: Hi Rob 
Did the var_dump.. see the output above.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the error reporting is different on the new server. Do a phpinfo() on each server and see what the difference is. Or check the php.ini files on each server.

If you don't have access to the ini files, you'll need to break down the error reporting value, which can be a pain.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

You'll be happy to hear you can override the php.ini error_reporting value in your code.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php